# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in basic python program comparing 2 excel spreadsheets

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked a few times but not sure exactly how to change my code to remove the above error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.read_excel('Excel1.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('Excel2.xlsx')

df1.equals(df2)

comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
print (comparison_values)

rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)

for item in zip(rows,cols):
        df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

df1.to_excel('./Excel_diff.xlsx',index=False,header=True)
```

I am getting the error on the rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False) line

Comment: numpy is considered basic nowadays? O_0

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` returns only one value. That's why you are getting error

so it should be like this:

`rows = np.where(...)`

Comment: This then gives me an error within the for loop as there is no index 1

Comment: provide your df1 and df2. I will update my code